# Html5 Input Slider not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, web-deployment

So, I have put a function to repeat every second using setinterval. This function updates the knob on the input slider. Problem is the moment i move the knob with my mouse, the knob stops moving. How can I make it so that the knob just jumps to what ever i is? Im using in chrome.

```
<input type="range" id="range" min="0" max="9999" step="1" value="0"/>

#range {
-webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
width: 20px;
height: 100px;
}

    i=0;
ytplayer_progressSlider = setInterval(function(){
    $("input").attr("value",i);
    i++;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Does the user need to be able to change the slider value? If not why not disable the input? If they do need to be able to change it, the browser wont let you stop updating the knob position to correlate with the mouse as this is necessary for the user to change the slider's value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.val(...)` instead of `.attr('value', ...)`.

Consider using `$range.val($range.val() + 1)` instead of keeping it in a variable, because if you keep it in a variable the slider will go back to where it was within one second, no matter what the user does.

Comment: OK, found a solution. You were on the right track. I used this instead of calling .attr `document.querySelector('input[id=range]').value = i++;`